GuildMemberUpdate event getting oldMember and newMember both false values about roles
My Discord bot uses the GuildMemberUpdate event to validate whether a specific role has been added/removed from users in a server, and based on this, it performs certain actions on a database.
The event is expected to do the following, and in fact, it works correctly:

Was role X added? Action 1 is performed.
Was role X removed? Action 2 is performed.

The issue arises when, for some reason, the bot needs to be restarted. After restarting, if role X is removed from a user who already had it previously, the event stops working as expected. It doesn't trigger either of the two conditions because, as seen in hasVipRoleNow and hadVipRoleBefore, both values are returned as false:
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.GuildMemberUpdate,
    async execute(oldMember, newMember) {
        // This variable has the ID of the official server.
        const guildId = 'MY_GUILD_ID';

        // This variable has the ID of the VIP User role.
        const vipRoleId = 'MY_ROLE_ID';

        // The conditional checks if the event was triggered in the official server.
        if (newMember.guild.id !== guildId) {
            return;
        }

        const oldRoles = oldMember.roles.cache;
        const newRoles = newMember.roles.cache;

        const hasVipRoleNow = newRoles.has(vipRoleId);
        const hadVipRoleBefore = oldRoles.has(vipRoleId);

        if (!hadVipRoleBefore && hasVipRoleNow) {
            try {
                managePremiumStatus(true, newMember);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

        if (hadVipRoleBefore && !hasVipRoleNow) {
            try {
                managePremiumStatus(false, newMember);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    },
};

The best approach I’ve come up with is to use a third if statement so that if both values are false, it performs the same behavior as the second if.
if (!hadVipRoleBefore && !hasVipRoleNow) {
    // Treat this area as the second 'if'.
}

However, I’m not sure if this is the correct solution or if there might be a better one.
